# ajuda armazenar valor do csv em um vetor EM C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>




int process_field2(int fcount, char *value) {
   
    int vetor[36];
    
    if (fcount == 0) {
    for (int k=0; k<36; k++){
        vetor[k] = atoi(value);}

    }
    printf("%d", vetor[1]);
 
    
}



int testes2(){
    
    char buf[1024];
    char token[1024];
    int row_count = 0;
    int fcount = 0;
    int in_double_quotes = 0;
    int token_pos = 0;
    int i = 0;
    
    FILE *fp = fopen("posgraduacaoresidencia.csv", "r");

    if (!fp) {
        printf("Can't open file\n");
        return 0;
    }


    while (fgets(buf, 1024, fp)) {
        row_count++;

        if (row_count == 1) {
            continue;
        }

        fcount = 0;
        i = 0;
        do {
            token[token_pos++] = buf[i];

            if (buf[i] == ';' ) {
                token[token_pos - 1] = 0;
                token_pos = 0;
                process_field2(fcount++, token);
                break;
        
}
        } while (buf[++i]);
    
        printf("\n");
        
    }
}







int main(void) {
  
    testes2();      
    return 0;
}
```

Porem esta armazenando todos os valores da coluna em cada uma das posiçoes do vetor, gostaria de armazenar cada dado da linha em 1 posiçao do vetor...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Me parece que está fazendo exatamente o que você programou para fazer. Dê um exemplo de uma entrada e o que você deseja como resultado. A função `process_field2` me parece sem sentido. Note também que `vetor` é uma variável local e portanto seu conteúdo se perde ao final da execução da função.

Comment: desejo como resultado que cada valor que esta na foto entre em uma posiçao do vetor, porem esta entrando todos os valores em cada posiçao do vetor, em vez de 1 valor em cada posiçao

Comment: Mas você passa apenas um valor para sua função! Você atribui este valor, convertido para inteiro, para todas as posições do vetor. Além disso a cada execução da função ela perde o que foi armazenado nas outras execuções. Repense sua lógica.

Comment: poderia me dar uma luz, to perdido kk

Comment: sou bem iniciante ainda, to começando agora e tal, porem estou com dificuldade para conseguir uma soluçao, to a dias ja tentando, preciso obter esses dados em um vetor para organizar eles por ordem crescente

Comment: Qual o conteudo do arquivo ?